# como creo un programa que escriba en consola una lista de numeros impares a partir de un digito insertado por el usuario

Tags: c#

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inserte un numero para ver la lista de numeros impares ");

            int X = 11;

            X = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i <= X; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2! = 0) ;

                else (i % 2! = 1);
                {
                    break;
                }
                {
                    Console.Write("," + i);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

quiero que la variable llamada "X" tenga un valor definido por el usuario pero no se como hacerlo esto es el codigo que he hecho

Comment: No funciona el código?

Comment: Claro que no funcionará con esos IF... por que tienes un IF cerrado con ; de inmediato ?

Comment: la variable X tiene un valor definido por el usuario. pero el resto del codigo es erroneo..

Comment: cual seria el requerimiento? los impares desde un número dado, pero hasta que n°?? cual es el límite?

Comment: gbianchi me podrias explicar la parte erronea del codigo y darme una solucion gracias

Answer (score 0):

Algo muy básico

Si es impar, crea una relación que muestra en pantalla 10 valores por encima del dado.

Si es par, le suma 1 y crea la misma lista de 10 valores por encima del dato

```
//pedimos el número por consola
Console.WriteLine("inserte un numero para ver la lista de numeros impares ");

        //llevamos a la variable x en número introducido por pantalla
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //creamos un variable de tope para el bucle que suma 10 al valor dado
        int tope = x + 10;

        //creamos el bucle for
        for (int i = 0; i <= tope; i++)
        {
            //si el número dato al dividirse por 2 da de resto distinto a 0 (impar)
            if (x % 2 != 0)
            {
                //tomamos el valor y vamos sumando de dos en dos creando impares
                x = x + 2;
                //imprimimos el valor actual seguido de una coma
                Console.Write(x + ",");
            }
            //si el resto es cero (número par)
            else
            {
                //al valor dado le sumamos 1
                x = x + 1;
                //vamos sumando de dos en dos para crear números impares correlativos
                x = x + 2;
                //imprimimos el valor actual en pantalla seguidos de una coma
                Console.Write(x + ",");
            }
        }
```